# Averaging elements of a list of matrices over time

Tags: matrix

Suppose that I have a time series of a matrix, say, for 3 periods.

```
t1={{0,3,0},{6,0,0},{3,6,0}};
t2={{0,6,0},{3,0,3},{0,6,0}};
t3={{0,3,6},{3,0,6},{3,3,0}};
```

> [image]

I want to take the average of each cell `[i,j]` over time by considering the number of `non-zero` elements only as follows:

> [image: Blockquote]

I went through the documentation of `Matrix Operations` but I could not find any thing close to what I describe above. Of course, one can use `Flatten`, `Sum` and `Partition` to accomplish what I want. However, I like to have a more elegant way to do the job using matrix structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Quiet @ Block[{Indeterminate = 0}, Total[#] / Total[Unitize @ #]] & @ {t1, t2, t3}

% // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 4 & 6 \\
>  4 & 0 & \frac{9}{2} \\
>  3 & 5 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also

```
Total[{t1, t2, t3}] / (Total[Unitize @ {t1, t2, t3}] /. 0 -> 1)
```

> same result

Comment: Your answers are perfect, just the type of answers I was thinking of. The first answer looks more elegant, though.

Comment: Thank you @TugrulTemel for the accept and kind words.

Comment: First solution gives a warning on M11.3  Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Comment: Thank you @OkkesDulgerci. Forgot to `Quiet`.

Comment: @kglr: Yes, I was going to ask why we receive warnings from the first method. There  is no room for warning because if all elements are zero, then the average is zero.

Comment: @Tugrul,  the zeros `Total[Unitize @ {t1, t2, t3}]` in the denominator are causing the warning message.

Answer (score 7):

```
Total[{t1, t2, t3}]/Clip[Total[Unitize@{t1, t2, t3}], {1, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it as a pipeline of functions, using [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html); a properly placed `Replace` gets rid of the warnings:

```
MapThread[
 List /* DeleteCases[0] /* Replace[{} -> {0}] /* Mean,
 {t1, t2, t3}, 2]

(* {{0, 4, 6}, {4, 0, 9/2}, {3, 5, 0}} *)
```